How to specify one type var must be a subclass of another type var in Python
I am trying to create an abstract API client class. For a concrete subclass of this, it will deal with API endpoints of a particular base class. Each specific endpoint will be a subclass of that base class.
I originally tried defining my abstract API client class as follows (simplified to just isolate the problem I am facing):
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar

from .endpoints import BaseGenericEndpoint

BaseClientEndpoint = TypeVar('BaseClientEndpoint', bound=BaseGenericEndpoint)
SpecificClientEndpoint = TypeVar('SpecificClientEndpoint',
                                 bound=BaseClientEndpoint)

class APIClient(ABC, Generic[BaseClientEndpoint]):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._endpoint_values: dict[str, BaseClientEndpoint] = {}

    def get_endpoint(
            self, endpoint_name: str,
            endpoint_type: Type[SpecificClientEndpoint]
    ) -> SpecificClientEndpoint:
        if endpoint_name not in self._endpoint_values:
            self._endpoint_values[endpoint_name] = endpoint_type()
        return self._endpoint_values[endpoint_name]

The problem is that the SpecificClientEndpoint line prompts pycharm to tell me Constraints cannot be parametrized by type variables. But without doing that, I don't know how to type annotate the fact that the argument/return value for the get_endpoint method have to be subclasses of BaseClientEndpoint (but don't have to be equal to it).
I think I can find hacky ways around this (perhaps by using BaseClientEndpoint throughout, and then having the subclasses use cast to enforce the desired outcome), but it seems like what I am wanting to do here isn't that weird, so I feel like there must be some more elegant solution to this that I am overlooking.
I've searched through the Python and mypy docs and haven't come up with an answer, and my Google research has also been fruitless. I've seen other people who were encountering this same error, but they were trying to accomplish something different, so the solutions proposed to them were not applicable to my case.

Are you making calls to get_endpoint with multiple values of endpoint_type for the same endpoint_name? If not, I don't see how subclassing is an issue. get_endpoint("foo", Bar) is always going to return an instance of Bar, whether or not it has to create it first. But if you call get_endpoint("foo", Bar), then get_endpoint("foo", Baz), then it may matter how Baz is related to Bar, since the cache is going to produce a value of type Bar.
